# Changing the form action dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form on my page that looks like so:

```
<form action="/home/email" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="email-form" method="post">
// form elements
</form>
```

Depending on the page, I would like to dynamically change the attributes of the form with jQuery; specifically the action attribute.

```
$('#send-email').click(function () {
   $('#email-form').attr('action', '@Url.Action("emailaccounting", "home")')
 )};
```

The jQuery above successfully renders to:

```
<form action="/home/emailaccounting" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="email-form" method="post">
// form elements
</form>
```

So I'm able to alter the form attributes when clicking a link that opens a popup form to send an email.  However, when I submit the form, the action that gets hit is the original - "email" not "emailaccounting".

I played around a bit more and on the submit click handler for the email form, I added the following:

```
  $('.send-email').click(function (e) {
    // The original form action post will be hit without this...
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#email-form').submit();
  };
```

With the above snippet, the correct action -- "emailaccounting" is called.  Why? I don't know...I'm hoping someone can explain that.  But I'm not out of the woods yet - I have an input element to upload a file.  Now when I try to upload a file on the same form that worked previously, I hit submit and it goes to the "email" action.  If I do not attempt to do a file upload, it hits the "emailaccounting" action.

1. Why does the e.preventDefault() followed by the submit of the form hit the correct action?
2. Why does uploading a file direct it to the original form action; not the one altered by jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating your problem? From your description everything should work fine, meaning that you have omitted something from the code you have shown here.

Comment: Can you post the html of the `send-email` button?  My guess is that this is being caused by something generated by .net.

Comment: Darin - I think it might be hard to demonstrate there only because the problem shows up on the server-side of things when I put breakpoints on the two different controller actions.

Comment: @Beavis, no it's easy to show. It is not really important what the server action does or if it returns 404. The important thing is to illustrate a script which picks the wrong action despite you changing it. That could be observed with FireBug of course.

Comment: @Darin Ok, let me try to setup jsfiddle...

Comment: @Beavis, great, while waiting, here's one which works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/T9FLh/3/

Comment: @Darin sorry, I don't have much experience with jsfiddle - was your action suppose to update?  I don't see any change when I hit the 'change action of form' button.

Comment: @Beavis, yes it updates the action the form, just observe the DOM with FireBug. And when you submit observe the Net tab in FireBug and you will see that it POSTs (as expected) to `/home/emailaccounting` instead of the original `/home/email`.

Comment: @Darin - I cut a lot out but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/V2PxL/3/.   There's a lot more to this but hopefully that gives you an idea.  I'm using ajax here with the jquery ajax form plugin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4082/discussion-between-beavis-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 7):

I tried like below and it worked for me

```
$('#send-email').click(function () {
   $('#email-form').attr('action', '/home/emailaccounting')
 )};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$('#email-form').attr('action', '<%= Url.Action("emailaccounting", "home") %>');
```

Comment: James - The action is being altered correctly (I verified the source html).  The problem is that the correct action in my controller is not being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just simply wanting the action to be the current page, whatever that is? If so, you can just use `action=""`.

You didn't mention which browser and version you're testing with or whether or not you've tried others. It might actually be a bug/security feature/idiosyncrasy of the browser. If that's the case, you could workaround that by simply sending the form via AJAX. Functionally, it's no different, you could even redirect the page after a successful response to make it behave the same. With AJAX, you could explicitly control the post URL without futzing with changing the action, though.

Comment: Chris - the action is altered fine.  I can see the source code change.  The problem is the odd behavior when I submit the form.  It's hitting the original action and not the one altered by jQuery.

Comment: I understand, but I was just checking to make sure you weren't trying to change the action just to make it the current page URL, because this would be a way to do that reliably, thus negating the problem entirely.

Comment: Chris - that is the case.  I will go ahead and try your suggestion even though the action seems to be just fine...

Comment: Yep, jQuery is changing it as it should, but never dismiss the potential for a browser to do completely boneheaded things it shouldn't ;). Having the action just be blank negates the need to change it via JavaScript and ends your problems without the headache of figuring out why the browser is stupid.